# Stuck in Portrait Mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I need to check if a user is logged in or not, and redirect them accordingly. After adding this code to my app delegate, my app is perpetually stuck in portrait mode and will not render in landscape. What did I do wrong? I heard something about not setting the root view properly, or adding subviews, or containers, etc, being an issue. Does anything appear incorrect below that might cause me to be stuck as I am?

Thanks!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    //Redirect user to either home screen, or login/register screen
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcLoginGateway") as UIViewController

    var userSettings = UserSettings()

    //Change gateway view controller to the home view controller if logged in
    if (userSettings.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UIViewController
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: I guess you set the orientation correctly. Does your app remains interactive after it freez?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up making my login gateway the initial view controller, and then in the app delegate I check this:

```
    if (userSettings.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
        var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UITabBarController
        self.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
    }
```

Now it only checks if you're logged in and if so redirects you accordingly. This worked and now I can rotate my device! Awesome. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your Device Orientation is checked for Landscape Left and Landscape Right? Check Build Target->General->Deployment Info-> Device Orientation

Comment: yah it's definitely the code above I pasted - when I alter it or remove it everything is good again

Answer (score 0):

Just check this:

```
var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcLoginGateway") as UIViewController

var userSettings = UserSettings()

//Change gateway view controller to the home view controller if logged in
if (userSettings.IsUserLoggedIn()) {
    initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UIViewController
}
```

You casted both as UIViewController but you should do this, lets assume you ViewCOntroller's name is `NameOfYouViewController`, so you should write:

```
initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as NameOfYouViewController
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: didn't seem to work :( (it worked in the sense the code worked, but nothing changed)